# Java to HSM connection and sending "GC" / FK" commands

Tags: java, connection, command, hsm

Here is code to send and receive data from HSM

```
public class TestHSMJava {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("<<< Main Method Entry >>>");
    String command = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    byte[] b= new byte[100];
    try {
        socket = new Socket("10.10.10.10", 7500);
        System.out.println("<<< Socket >>> :" + socket);
        if (socket != null) {
            System.out.println("<<< Connected to HSM  >>>:"
                    + socket.isConnected());
            in = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new DataOutputStream (new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            command = "0006303030304e43";
            out.writeUTF(command);
            System.out.println("Input to HSM : " +command);
            out.flush();
            String response = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Output from HSM : " +response);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

The questions is which command I need to send for execute "GC" command (Translate a ZPK from LMK to ZMK Encryption) I need to generate a clear components for TPK-key. Usually I do

```
gc
Enter key length [1,2,3]: 2
Enter key type: 002
Enter key scheme: u
```

and then

```
fk
Enter key length [1,2,3]: 2
Enter key type: 002
Enter key scheme: u
Enter component type [X,H,T,E,S]: x
Enter number of components [1-9]: 2
```

I need to do those actions using Java-program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generation of components and forming of a key are typically console actions. Having generated and formed the key the result would be used in the GC translate command

if you need to generate a key via the host command you can use the A0 command and use the output from that in the GC command

I can probably help you more through the official channels. If you have a support contract please email the help desk and mention that you've submitted a question on stackoverflow and the email should make its way to me

---

if you're looking for help regarding the java code above:

you basically just need to substitute the value in "command" for the command you want to send

you currently have

```
command = "0006303030304e43";
```

this translates to `0000NC` with the 1st two bytes containing the length in bytes - 0006

if you want to send  `A00002U` (0=generate; 002=tpk;u=key scheme) you should prepend this with a header, e.g., `0000` and prepend the whole string with the length

the command to send is then `0000A00002U` which is 11 bytes

so the command, in bytes, to send to the hsm is

```
command = "000b3030303041303030303255";
```

Comment: I tried sending same command to my HSM, but the reply I got was 000b3030303041303030303135, which when converted to ASCII is 0000A000015. What could be the issue here?

Comment: `printf '000b3030303041303030303255' | xxd -r -p | nc localhost 9998`
/0000A100UD380C66E7D96F2B36592FA8EFFE9A5AFFD9184 with `vmantek/thales-sim`